# Explaining how to solve this differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm a newcomer to this kind of problem so I found this one quite difficult: $$y''+4y'+13y=1-x$$ Could anybody help me understand? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This equation is a standard second order nonhomogenuous differential equation. First, find the homogeneous solution and then find the particular solution through undetermined coefficients or variation of parameters techniques. Could you update your post and show us what you have done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linear, second-order, non-homogeneous (not 0 on the right-hand side of the equation) ordinary differential equation.

The solution will be made up of two parts as with any second-order, non-homogeneous equation: the complementary solution and the particular integral.

So first, you need to find the complementary solution, which is the solution if the right hand side were 0.

So, $y'' + 4y' + 13y = 0$.

We assume that $y$ is an exponential function - only the exponential function when differentiated gives a multiple of itself, allowing the different derivatives to cancel to give 0.

Let $y=e^{rx}$. 
Then:
$$y'= re^{rx}$$
$$y''= r^2 e^{rx}$$
Plugging these into the homogeneous equation:
$$r^2e^{rx} + 4re^{rx} + 13 e^{rx} = 0$$
$$e^{rx}(r^2+4r+13)=0$$
An exponential term can never be 0, so the remaining quadratic, known as the auxiliary equation or characteristic equation, must be 0:
$$r^2 + 4r + 13 = 0$$

Solving, we get complex roots $-2 \pm 3i$. It is a known result that if the characteristic equation has complex roots $\alpha \pm \beta i$, then the complementary solution is:
$$c_1e^{\alpha x} \cos(\beta x) + c_2e^{\alpha x} \sin(\beta x)$$

So, **our** complementary solution takes the form:
$$y_c = c_1e^{-2x}\cos(3x) + c_2e^{-2x}\sin(3x)$$

Next, we need to find the particular integral, $y_p$, the solution that **actually** solves the differential equation.

Looking at the right hand side of the original differential equation, we formulate a trial solution of the form $Ax+B$ (a polynomial of degree 1) for the particular integral. 
$$y_p = Ax+B$$
$$y_p'= A$$
$$y_p'' = 0$$

Plugging these back into the equation, we get:
$$0 + 4A + 13(Ax+B) = 1-x$$
Equating coefficients:
$$13A = -1$$
$$\therefore A= \frac{-1}{13}$$. 
$$4A + 13B = 1$$
$$\therefore B = \frac{17}{169}$$.

Our overall solution is the sum of the complementary solutions and particular integral:
$$y = c_1e^{-2x}\cos(3x) + c_2e^{-2x}\sin(3x) - \frac{1}{13}x + \frac{17}{169}$$

Answer (score 1):

*A summary of the method*: you have to

1. Solve the associated homogeneous linear differential equation $\;y''+4y'+13y=0$. It is an equation with constant coefficients, so you can try to find *exponential* solutions: $\mathrm e^{rx}$ , for a relevant $r$, which leads to the *characteristic equation*:
   $$r^2+4r+13=0.$$
2. Find a particular solution of the complete equation. As the r.h.s. is a polynomial,  a solution will be a polynomial of the same degree, which you can find by the method of indeterminate coefficients.
3. Add the particular solution to the general solution of the homogeneous solution (which is a vector  space of dimension $2$, so you need to obtain two linearly independent solutions).